# Convert query from "LIKE" query to "MATCH AGAINST" (FULLTEXT index )

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

Hi Below is my query in which I am using "LIKE" on prenom and nom fields in sql. I want to convert that query into MATCH AGAINST so, I can use FULLTEXT index applied on those fields. Need suggestion.

```
SELECT `Pers`.`persID`, `Pers`.`name`, `Pers`.`nom`, `Pers`.`prenom` 
FROM `bdrplus`.`pers` AS `Pers`   
WHERE `Pers`.`prenom` LIKE 'j%' AND `Pers`.`nom` LIKE 's%' AND `Pers`.`etat` = 1   
ORDER BY  `Pers`.`prenom` ASC, `Pers`.`nom` ASC
```

How can I write above query with MATCH and AGAINST in mysql?

Comment: full text index for just one character thats pretty odd. Full text indexes are meant to be for word search which gives you best result.

Comment: Yes, Actually I want those records which first name starts with "j" and last name start with "s". Can I use Fulltext on this type of query?

Comment: Well you can use boolean mode and setting the `ft_min_word_len = 1` in the my.cf for mysql config http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html